# Adding a statement to correctly hide/unhide rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that will hide rows when a topic is "closed" It works flawlessly until the point where I close a new topic.

The issue is that typical use of the sheet will have all closed topics hidden. So when I change an open topic to closed, and run this macro, it will un-hide all hidden topics, but hide the newest one (essentially because this code is just reversing itself back and forth).

I need to add a statement so that it will un-hide all hidden topics, and **NOT** hide the newest "closed" topic. Hard for me to explain, so I am sorry for that.

```
Set Rng = Range("A11:A1000")
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If MyCell.Value = "Closed" Then
        If MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        End If
Next MyCell

With ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1")
        If .Caption = "Hide" Then
            .Caption = "Show"
        Else
            .Caption = "Hide"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Okay, so in the first image is an example of me "closing" a topic. I simply change "open" to "close" and it flags green. **NOTE**: **All** previously closed topics are currently **HIDDEN**.

[image: Before Show]

When I run this macro to "Show" it will un-hide all hidden rows, however it will now HIDE the row that I just changed to "Closed" due to the fact that it was not previously hidden. You can see that when all are shown, Row 33 is hidden.

[image: After Show]

Comment: What is the specific question?
 Are you requesting to have the job done for you?

Comment: how do you determine what the *newest "closed"* topic is?

Comment: Also, instead of using `if`s I would rather write `MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = Not MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden`

Comment: I have added more of a description with images to my OP. This macro is just setting the value of all cells with "Closed" to either hidden or not hidden (opposite of what they are), where I need to it un-hide ALL cells with "Show" and hide "Closed" cells with "Hide"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) The statement `MyCell.Value = "Closed"` returns a boolean value (`true` or `false`). So you can just do (As an example):

```
  MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = (MyCell.Value = "Closed")
```

The parentheses are superfluous, but it makes it clearer what is happening so I include them. This just sets the row to hidden when the value is "closed". Nice and simple. If the value isn't "Closed" then the row is unhidden. You can multiply (or `AND`) two boolean statements together to get more complex results. `True*False = False`, `True*True=True`

2) To work with your button maybe consider changing the caption FIRST and then reacting to the new value.

Combining those two changes together you can do something like:

```
With ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1")
    If .Caption = "Hide" Then
        .Caption = "Show"
    Else
        .Caption = "Hide"
    End If
End With

Set Rng = Range("A11:A1000")
For Each MyCell In Rng
    MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = (ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").Caption <> "Hide" And MyCell.Value2 = "Closed")
Next MyCell
```

All the confusing boolean stuff aside, you could switch over to using an autofilter to attack your hide/show so you don't have to iterate your huge range:

```
Sub button_click()
    If ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").caption = "Show" Then
        ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").caption = "Hide"
        Range("A10:A1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Closed", VisibleDropDown:=False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").caption = "Show"
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. I have some things to learn from that last line of code because I don't fully understand it, but it works flawless.

Comment: I've updated the answer to do away with boolean stuff and the for loop. You might want to consider just using autofilter. It's a TON quicker than iterating and hiding and it's easier on the eyes.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, as well as much easier. Can't believe I didn't consider that to begin with. Thanks!